# Set Image View Resource through XML array -- TypedArray

Tags: imageview, adt, android-imageview, eclipse-adt, typed-arrays

I am working on android project using ADT. I have a XML array through which i created a typedArray in my Java code. I am trying to set ImageView resource through that typed array but i am unable to do it.

Kindly help me in this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

found that .. there is an getDrawable function in typedArray.
And that drawable can be used to send ImageView.setImageDrawable function.